# How to deploy symfony rest api project in hosting without third-party applications?

Tags: symfony, deployment, hosting

I am trying to deploy symphony api project in hosting.

Until now, all the projects I have done have been pure php, uploading to hosting is simple and everything always works perfectly.

The situation with symfony is tragic and impossible for me, uploading the code just does not work.

I'm really very disappointed with the framework... deploying react, angular is so easy and here it's just ridiculously impossibly hard...

My question is not specific but I'm sure if there is a good answer it will be useful for thousands like me!

Can someone help me with this please? Any tutorial, video etc.

For 3 days I have been searching for information on Google and YouTube from morning to night all day like crazy.
I would appreciate it if someone could just send me a link to a blog tutorial or a video that works without third party applications. I am really tired...

Comment: Have you read the [deployment steps from the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html)?

Comment: Symfony uses composer for dependancies. So you will need to ensure that when you run `composer install` you have set up the correct platform requirements e.g php version or any php plugins etc.

Could you confirm what errors you are getting ?

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for taking time to write. There are a lot of errors when I run composer install... here are-> https://pastebin.com/32nbpcXj

Comment: @dashadow, the depreciation's will be from your Symfony version but these are just notices for now. Try running `composer self-update --2` to update Composer itself to V2, that is what the errors are telling you..

Comment: @Bossman  I tried that too, but I get a bunch of other errors. I've tried almost everything I've found on the internet over the past few days, but nothing works.  It seems symphony is dying and abandoned. I will switch to laravel. Thanks for your time I appreciate it.

Comment: @dashadow, *"It seems symphony is dying and abandoned"*. Because you have these errors? The errors you have don't have anything to do with Symfony, the packages have dependencies that you need to work through, they are telling you what you need. You will probably find Laravel will show exactly the same messages. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the whole problem was in the version of composer, which is 1.0.0 in the hosting, which creates hundreds of errors and it is simply impossible to install the project written on the latest version.

All I had to do was manually install the latest version of composer on the hosting.

Then I install the project using the composer phar file
`php ~/composer.phar install`
instead of the default one which from the hosting is the oldest version 1.0.0 and bring impossible to fix problems.

If anyone has a similar problem just check the composer version in the hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony is alive and well, just had a major developer conference in Paris days ago. Symfony has a new minor release every 6 months, a new version 6.2 will be released in the coming days.

Just make sure to follow the information for deployment linked above as well as the setup requirements: https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html#symfony-tech-requirements. Perhaps you are trying to run Symfony 6.1 with PHP lower than 8.1?

As to other backend frameworks like Laravel (which is based in part on Symfony): Almost everything in PHP land nowadays is using Composer for easy installation. Any hosting environment that provides SSH access should allow you to setup/use Composer.

A common pipeline to roll out projects can be IDE > GitHub > server. You can however use SFTP as well, just make sure that the program you are using follows the .gitignore file and doesn't try to upload everything. Afterwards run Composer and Yarn/NPM to install everything that your project needs.

Comment: Hi, I hope they will fix the bugs&problems in the next release (there are a lot). Yes, I use PHP version 8.1 with Symfony 6.1. Of course, I am using composer. I am connecting to hosting with git bash using SSH. I switched to laravel (much better in my opinion) and everyting works awesome without any problems and errors for now. If you know (or have) blog tutorial or youtube tutorial explaying step by step how to deploy symfony will be awesome and helpful for a lot of people, I am sure. Thank you for your time, I appreciate it.